# HTML not responding with JavaScript filter

Tags: javascript

This is an update to a previous question I had. I am making a simple page that filters the first 9 Pokemon by their type after clicking a button. I will include the code below. I ran the code through a validator and there were no issues. Also, I don't see any errors in the console. I did console the type and the array every time a button is clicked so it looks like the filter is working. But, nothing is happening on the page.

Here's a link to the page: https://sobreratas.github.io/pokemonfilter/

```js
const pokemon=[{name:"Bulbasaur",image:"images/bulbasaur.png",number:1,type:"Grass"},{name:"Ivysaur",image:"images/ivysaur.png",number:2,type:"Grass"},{name:"Venusaur",image:"images/venusaur.png",number:3,type:"Grass"},{name:"Charmander",image:"images/charmander.png",number:4,type:"Fire"},{name:"Charmeleon",image:"images/charmeleon.png",number:5,type:"Fire"},{name:"Charizard",image:"images/charizard.png",number:6,type:"Fire"},{name:"Squirtle",image:"images/squirtle.png",number:7,type:"Water"},{name:"Wartortle",image:"images/wartortle.png",number:8,type:"Water"},{name:"Blastoise",image:"images/blastoise.png",number:9,type:"Water"}];

const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');
const btnContainer = document.querySelector('.btn_container');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  displayPokemonMenu();
  displayMenuButtons();
})

function displayPokemonMenu(array) {
  let pokemonMap = pokemon.map(function(item) {
    return `<div class="pokemon-item">
            <img class="photo" src="${item.image}" alt="${item.name}">
            <h2>${item.name}</h2>
            <h3># <span id="number">${item.number}</span></h3>
            <h4>Type: <span id="type">${item.type}</span></h4>
        </div>`
  })
  pokemonMap = pokemonMap.join('');
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = pokemonMap;
}


function displayMenuButtons() {
  let types = pokemon.reduce(function(values, item) {
    if (!values.includes(item.type)) {
      values.push(item.type);
    }
    return values
  }, ['All']);

  const typesBtns = types.map(function(type) {
    return `<button class="filter-btn" data-id="${type}">${type}</button>`
  }).join('');

  btnContainer.innerHTML = typesBtns;

  const filterBtns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');

  filterBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let type = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      console.log(type)
      const pokemonFilter = pokemon.filter(function(item) {
        if (type === item.type) {
          return item;
        }
      })
      if (type === 'All') {
        displayPokemonMenu(pokemon);
      } else {
        displayPokemonMenu(pokemonFilter);
        console.log(pokemonFilter);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
<br>
<br>
<div class="btn_container">
  <button class="filter-btn" data-id="All">All</button>
</div>
<div class="section-center">
  <div class="pokemon-item">
    <img class="photo" src="images/bulbasaur.png" alt="Bulbasaur">
    <h2>Bulbasaur</h2>
    <h3># <span id="number">1</span></h3>
    <h4>Type: <span id="type">Grass</span></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, in `displayPokemonMenu` you are using the `pokemon` array (all Pokemons) instead of the `array` argument (filtered list).

Comment: `displayPokemonMenu(pokemonFilter);` passes in the filtered data but the function is ignoring that and using the original dataset. So when the page loads: `displayPokemonMenu(pokemon);`, and change `pokemon.map` in the function to `array.map` instead.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick comments. That fixed it and I learned a lesson from this. Thanks so much!